# Internal Implementation of Qsort

Tags: c, qsort

qsort is declared as

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
            int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

I want to know how does qsort implements the reflection property. I mean how does it call the function whose name we passed ?

Comment: Function pointers are well defined types in the language standard, and there is no reflection magic of any kind there.

Comment: There are no names being passed. A function pointer is passed.

Comment: @Charlie - semantics question, is it not true that 'name' is used synonymously with 'symbol' in terms of referring to functions? _function whose name we passed?_ seems a reasonable phrase.

Comment: Charlie made a point here. The look of the `qsort` call is clear : it seems that we just have to pass the _name_ of the function. What is occurring is that the given _name_ is actually a symbol which is a function pointer towards the required function and is interpreted as is.

Comment: @ryyker, I suppose when I saw "name" and "reflection" so close to together, I thought the OP meant "string" when he said "name". Probably better if I had said "no strings are being passed".

Comment: @Rerito - Whats really cool about that feature in C is that you can easily prepare and pass variations of "compare", say for strings, one for floats, one for ints, etc.  It just requires a definition for each.

Comment: @ryyker I know, it's very useful to sort exotic data structures as well, I was just trying to explain my understanding of what the OP meant by _passing the name_.

Answer (score 19):

`qsort` receives a pointer to function receiving two pointers and returning `int`, and that's just it. This pointer is called `compar`. All qsort needs to do to call this function is something like:

```
(*compar)(base+i, base+j);
```

Where `i` and `j` are offsets for `base`. It's really that simple. You can see a possible implementation in K&R second edition, section 5.11, page 120:

```
void qsort(void *v[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *)) {
    int i, last;
    void swap(void *v[], int, int);

    if (left >= right)
        return;
    swap(v, left, (left + right)/2);
    last = left;
    for (i = left+1; i <= right; i++)
        if ((*comp)(v[i], v[left]) < 0) /* Here's the function call */
            swap(v, ++last, i);
    swap(v, left, last);
    qsort(v, left, last-1, comp);
    qsort(v, last+1, right, comp);
}
```

Comment: It's very nice to quote a reference ... +1

Comment: Can you explain why there's `int left, int right` instead of `size_t array_size, size_t elm_size`?

Comment: Why does the function need to be casted to (*compar)?

Answer (score 0):

what `qsort` receives is a pointer to function  , so all it needs to do in order to use that function is to sort of dereference that pointer .