# Generic insertion sort in C

Tags: c, sorting, generics, insertion

I have coded a generic insertion sort in C, and it works really fine.

But, On my function of insertion sort, it gets a `void** arr`,
and on its signature it gets a `void* arr`, otherwise, it doesn't work.

Why is it so?
Do we have any other ways to code the insertion sort to be generic?

The Full code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define SIZE 10
int cmp(void* elm1, void* elm2);
void insertionSort(void* arr, int size);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {5, 8, 2, 3, 15, 7, 4, 9, 20, 13};
    int arr2[] =  {1};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
    insertionSort(&arr, SIZE);
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}

void insertionSort(void** arr, int size)
{
    int i = 1;
    int j;
    void* temp;
    while (i < size)
    {
        if (cmp(arr[i], arr[i-1]) == -1)
        {
            temp = arr[i];
            j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && cmp(arr[j], temp) == 1)
            {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                j--;
            }
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int cmp(void* elm1, void* elm2)
{
    if ((int)elm1 == (int)elm2)
        return 0;
    else if ((int)elm1 > (int)elm2)
        return 1;
    else 
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code as it is, is undefined, because of multiple problems. It just happens to work, because on your system the size of the pointer is the same as the size of the type `int`.

You code will not compile without warnings (if you enable them). The function insertionSort and it's prototype must have the same type.

You should change the type in the function definition to

```
void insertionSort(void* arr, int size)
```

And then cast the pointer arr, to an appropriate type. Since this is a generic sort, like qsort(), the only realistic option is a cast to `char*`. This means you will also have to pass the size of the type into the function, so the pointer can be incremented correctly. This will require you to change the function drastically.

So, the function prototype should really be the same as qsort:

```
void Sort(void* arr, size_t size , size_t object_size , int(*)( const void* , const void* ))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `integers` are not pointers, so your test array is of type `*int` or `int[]`. But in your function, you don't know that and you try to make your code work with pointers. So you expect `* void[]`. If you change your `temp` variable to `int`, you don't need the `**` in the signature. The same way, if you want to keep the "generic" (as you call), you need an array of `*int`.

Basically, in C you cannot write a function working out of the box for both primary types and pointers. You need some tricks. Have a look at [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19437135/internal-implementation-of-qsort), maybe it will help.